# Utilizar 2 metodos con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un menú que al hacer click en un botón, dicho botón se debería ocultar, ya realice la animación pero quiero añadirle el método `.hide()` para que lo oculte.

Lo primero que intente fue lo siguiente:

```
$("#boton").click(function() {
    $("#navbar").animate({
        left: '-100%',
        opacity: '0.5',
    }, 1500);
});
```

Luego al intentar añadirle el metodo `.hide()`:

```
$("#boton").click(function() {
        $("#navbar").hide().animate({
            left: '-100%',
            opacity: '0.5',
        }, 1500);
    });
```

Pero al realizar lo siguiente, lo oculta y no realiza la animación.

- **HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <nav class="col-3" id="navbar">
            <ul>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main class="col">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">

              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="boton">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

            </nav>

          </main>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿quieres que la animación oculte el botón? si usas `$("#navbar")` lo estas aplicando al `<nav>`, si quieres aplicarlo al botón deberías usar `$(this)`.

Comment: Hola @the-breaker lo que busco es que al dar click al botón, se oculte el elemento que tiene el id `navbar` pero realizando la animación que puse en el ejemplo, ya ocultarlo lo hace, el problema es que no realiza la animación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar `setTimeout` para darle tiempo a la animación de acabar antes de que se oculte

```js
$("#boton").click(function() {
    $("#navbar").animate({
        left: '-100%',
        opacity: '0',
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#navbar").hide();
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <nav class="col-3" id="navbar">
            <ul>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
              <li>
                Ejemplo
              </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main class="col">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">

              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="boton">
                  Boton <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

            </nav>

          </main>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: El elemento se oculta muy rápido, debes darle mas tiempo.

Comment: así esta mejor.